# SSH + Sudo + Expect in Bash script: Run command with sudo in remote machine

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ssh, sudo, expect

I am trying to automate the deploy of some .deb packages with an script. I want to execute `sudo dpkg -i $myDeb.deb` in a list of remote machines I can access with ssh.

I've tried to automate the command with 'expect' inside a bash script, but I am obviously doing something wrong because I get a number of different errors (depending on where I put the quotation marks, basically)

This is the function I have (will be called with something like: `_remoteInstallation "myPackage115.deb" "192.168.1.55"`. I know that in the remote machine, the .deb is going to be located in $HOME/Documents/:

```
function _remoteInstallation(){
    local retval=1
    local debToInstall=$(basename "$1")
    local remoteMachine="$2"
    spawned=$(expect -d -c "
          set timeout 1800
          spawn "/usr/bin/ssh -t borrajax@$remoteMachine /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/dpkg -i /home/borrajax/Documents/$debToInstall"'
          expect {
                \"Are you sure you want to continue connecting\" { send \"yes\r\"; exp_continue }
                \"password\" { send \"myPassword\r\";  exp_continue }
                \"[sudo] password\" { send \"myPassword\r\";  exp_continue }
                default { exit 1 }
          }
    " )
    retval=$?
    return $retval
}
```

With the quotes in the spawned area like that, I get

```
expect: invalid option -- 't'
```

If I change it to:

```
 spawn /usr/bin/ssh -t borrajax@$remoteMachine '/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/dpkg -i /home/borrajax/Documents/$debToInstall'
```

It looks like is trying to run the sudo dpkg command locally (first ssh(s) to '$remoteMachine' and then runs sudo dpkg locally, like two separate commands)

With this:

```
spawn '/usr/bin/ssh -t borrajax@$remoteMachine \'/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/dpkg -i /home/borrajax/Documents/$debToInstall\''
```

I get that `couldn't execute "'/usr/bin/ssh": no such file or directory` (which is not true)

... and at this point, I ran out of ideas... **:-)**

Any hint will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Also posted on unix&linux http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42252/4667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I use for a similar issue is putting all the remote-script into a file, say `/usr/local/bin/debinstall.sh`. My suggestion for that in your case would be: Have a special directory where you drop the packages into -- let's call it `/tmp/remoteinstall` to have an example. Additionally, put the user you connect to into the `/etc/suduers` file, and permit it to execute `sudo dpkg -i *` without being prompted for a password. `debinstall.sh` then would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /tmp/remoteinstall
sudo dpkg -i *.deb && rm -f *
```

Make this script owned by  and `chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/debinstall.sh`.

Locally, your job would simply be to upload your .deb files and call the script:

```
cd /path/to/files
scp * user@remotemachine:/tmp/remoteinstall
ssh user@remotemachine /usr/local/bin/debinstall.sh
```

`debinstall.sh` would then install your packages, and afterwards empty the directory *only when the install finished successfully*.

In case something is missing in the `$PATH`, remember that neither `.bashrc` nor `.profile` are executet this way -- so you might want to either source them at the beginning of the remote script, or define the appropriate PATH there.

Comment: It turns out that the brackets in the \"[sudo]\" option were messing it up. I finally got it working with the spawn area looking like: spawn /usr/bin/ssh -t zignage@$remoteMachine \"/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/dpkg -i /home/zignage/Documents/$debToInstall\" and scaping the braces in sudo (\"\\[sudo\\]\")

Comment: Glad to read you've got it solved! In that case your variant has the advantage to require only maintenance on one machine ;)